# PL SQL Parameter List Empty

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

If I have a PL SQL procedure like this:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure get_age (first_name varchar(40), last_name varchar(50))

Begin

Select age
From Person
Where first = first_name AND last = last_name;

End;
```

It is not guaranteed that the user will pass in a value for the `first_name` and `last_name` variable.

How do I account for this in the Procedure above since I do not want the `first_name` or `last_name` in the `Where` clause of my query if either one of those variables do not have a value.

Comment: I assume that this is not the actual code that you have.  Parameters do not have lengths and a `select` in a procedure would have to have an `into` or it has to be used to open a cursor.  If you are just retrieving a value, you'd want a function not a procedure.  If either parameter is optional, you could get multiple rows so what would you want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is good as it is now, you can accept null values in your `WHERE` clause:

```
Where (first = first_name OR first_name is NULL) AND (last = last_name OR last_name in NULL);
```

This way the user can enter first and last names, first or last names only or neither and results will be selected as expected.

Comment: Thanks for replying. When you say `first_name is NULL` and `last_name in NULL` in the where clause is that setting the parameter `first_name` and `last_name` to NULL? So what will be the output of this where clause if the user doesn't pass in any first_name or last_name as parameters? Since you set the parameters to NULL in the where but how does that affect the where clause?

Comment: Hey so this just takes input from the user, first_name last_name.  So Basically when they enter a first and last name it selects only rows with matches for first AND last as entered.  If they omit an argument then the test is automatically passed.  So if they enter no first_name, the where clause is (TRUE) AND (last = last_name), this case enables the user to search by last name only .  They they enter no arguments (TRUE) AND (TRUE) all rows are returned.  It's a pretty dynamic function

Answer (score 0):

Create Or Replace Procedure get_age (first_name varchar(40) default null, last_name varchar(50) default null)

Begin

Select age From Person Where first = nvl(first_name,first) AND last = nvl(last_name,last);

End;